# Не получается от клиента отправить сообщение боту

Tags: python, telegram

есть код на pythone

```
import requests

# URL для отправки запросов к Telegram Bot API
base_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'

# Токен вашего бота
token = '6081043986:AAH5S6UlBipVleEWY3zVXuImsb6-3NtdMXI'

# ID вашего бота
bot_id = '6081043986'

# ID вашего клиента
client_id = '530460769'

# Текст сообщения
message_text = 'Start'

# Формирование URL для отправки сообщения
send_message_url = f'{base_url}{token}/sendMessage'

# Параметры запроса
params = {
    'chat_id': bot_id,
    'text': message_text
}

# Отправка POST-запроса к Telegram Bot API для отправки сообщения от клиента к боту
response = requests.post(send_message_url, params=params)

# Проверка статуса ответа
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Сообщение успешно отправлено.')
else:
    print('Ошибка при отправке сообщения.')
```

вроде все правильно с id бота клиента и api токеном но получаю ошибку при отправке сообщений